# Having issues mapping from a simple list to a corresponding property in a ViewDto

Tags: collections, automapper

I have a collection of "Alerts" (List) that I need to map to a property in a more complex class.
My destination class hierarchy is as follows:

```
public class BaseReplyDto<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public List<ErrorType> Errors { get; set; }
    public T ReplyData { get; set; }
}


public class GetAllAlertsReplyViewDto : BaseReplyDto<List<Alert>>{}
```

My Mapper configuration is this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<List<Alert>, GetAllAlertsReplyViewDto>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Errors, opt => opt.Ignore())
;
```

When I run the app, I get a mapper validation error:

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: 
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.

## Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type

List`1 -> GetAllAlertsReplyViewDto (Destination member list)

### System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[bioSynq.Infrastructure.Entities.Concrete.Alert, bioSynq.Infrastructure.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> bioSynq.Infrastructure.ViewDtos.DisplayAlertsArea.GetAllAlertsReplyViewDto (Destination member list)

ReplyData

Basically, it's telling me I need to provide some configuration to map my list of Alerts into the list of alerts that is my ReplyData property.

I've mucked around with about twenty different versions of syntax (.ForMember,  .ForSourceMember, etc), but can't find the right syntax to get what seems to be a very simple mapping of one list into another.

Anyone know the correct syntax to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your mapping configuration I don't see configuration for property `public List<Alert> ReplyData { get; set; }` from `GetAllAlertsReplyViewDto` class. My guess is that you need something like this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<List<Alert>, GetAllAlertsReplyViewDto>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Errors, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForMember(dest => dest.ReplyData , opt => opt.MapFrom(list => list));
```

Hope it'll help.